# TouchID not working for one user on a MacMini M2 Pro

Tags: password, mac-mini, touch-id

I had touch ID working with two user account on a MacMini, but recently it's stop working for one user.

I removed the fingerprint saved but that didn't fixed anything, I also changed the user password but nothing...

Also password through the AppleWatch was working but since I changed the password it doesn't even work

[image: TouchID settings]

[image: AppleWatch password]